# insert space after and before in string at specific index multiple times javascript p5.js

Tags: javascript, string, p5.js

```
str = '12512';
indexes = [0, 3]
lngth = 2;
```

result should be:  `str = ' 12 5 12 '`

How do I add spaces there, knowing the character length, and index at which they are located?

I tried to do it with

```
for (i=0; i<indexes.length; i++){
     var spb = [str.slice(0, indexes[i]), " ", str.slice(indexes[i])].join('');
     var spa = [str.slice(0, indexes[i]+lngth), " ", str.slice(indexes[i]+lngth)].join('');
       console.log(spb);
       console.log(spa);
    }
```

It seems to work, though the output is like this, cause i needed to search for each index:

```
spa 12 512
spb  12512
spa 12512 
spb 125 12
```

How to make output like this `' 12 5 12 '`

Comment: *"result should be:  `str = ' 12 5 12 '`"* What's the logic for that? If you just insert a space at index 0 and index 3, the result is `' 12 512'`, not `' 12 5 12 '`.

Comment: what is the meaning of length?

Comment: but i detemined length of my "substring", which in this example is 2.
By that i added extra indexes which are connected wiht length of substring, cause i need to have also space before the substring. 
In the example i didn't showd my substring function, but i just presented the length of it, which should work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to iterate backwards

```
for (i = indexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   str = str.slice(0, indexes[i] + lngth) + " " + str.slice(indexes[i] + lngth);
   str = str.slice(0, indexes[i]) + " " + str.slice(indexes[i]);
}
```

Why?

Otherwise the indices gets mixed up, for example after inserting one space all following indices are shifted by one. Iterating backwards avoids this.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please comment so I can improve the answer.

Comment: Ye this one works, atleast for this example, where there is only one sequence that repeats. 
Im currently have problem with making space to example like this `5126127138139` cause it put spaces only on 13, and not 12, but that might be a problem with my substring function ;p

Comment: @ElKolorado, please add the result to the string.

Comment: ye i reorganised my substring function on now it works, as return i got 
`5 12 6 12 7 13 8 13 9`

Though i saw other problem now, that im not sure how to solve. If there are any sequences that repeats, and also they contain any part of other sequence, then it should make spaces only at it borders. To show this on example: `5121215` repeats are `12,21`, the result i get is `5 1 21 21 5`. But i want to achieve something like this `5 12121 5`